# Buttons are stretched when I use in android:layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I use in android:layout_weight.
Its is helpful tool.

But it's problem when I use him. All buttons are in linear layout.
I want that buttons will be in same space between them. but in actual thay buttons stretched all the layout.

Its is possibility to use layout_weight for equal space but without stretched the buttons all the  layout?

I think maybe to put any button in linear layout and use on them with layout_weight or maybe use in margin(but this not dynamicly split in all screens size)

> 

```
<LinearLayout
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patient_p1_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/patient_p1_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patient_p2_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/p2_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patient_p3_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/p3_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patient_data_main_screen_medicines_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/medication_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patient_p4_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/p4_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use now in android:layout_marginBottom in  the button and it's work for me. but i don't sure that is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to it:

I use in fictitious view like this, when i use layout_weight only on the fictitious view :  (in my case TextView)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:text_view_element="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/patient_data_main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container_main_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingLeft="1.5dip"
        android:paddingTop="1.6dip"
        android:paddingRight="1.5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/details_main_screen_background"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/data_main_screen_details"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/data_main_screen_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/details_main_button_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_screen_tests_results_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/tests_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_screen_visits_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/visits_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_screen_med_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/med_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_screen_sens_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/sens_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_screen_information_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/information_selector" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `match_parent` for the `android:layout_height` and if you want some space between then you could put some empty views (or `Space`) and give them weights also. If you don't want for the buttons to  change the size, and you just want them to be placed symmetrically in the screen you can give them `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and surround each `Button` inside a `RelativeLayout` that will have the `android:layout_weight` set to a specific value.

Comment: I use in android:layout_marginBottom. i think that is like empty views. what you suggest about RelativeLayout - i want that it was be dynamicly to all screens size

Comment: marginBottom is not like empty views, you can give the empty views weights, so they will resize according to the screen size (not fix sizes). If you use RelativeLayout, you won't need any empty views, and you can have the buttons have the height wrap_content for example. Both of this methods will work for any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

this code does exactly that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/notif"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_unread"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_notify"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" 
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_notif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_notify"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```